# Ways to commit as a different user in subversion without prompting for a password

Tags: svn

We are working on a system to do a automated developer build and test before committing to the branch so that the branch is always in a good shape. The common account takes the patch from the developer and builds, tests and then commits it. The entire process happens in a separate pool of machines. The question is, is there a way to commit the code as a different user without svn prompting for a password. We use subversion 1.6 and http access method.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--username` and `--password` parameters to pass the user name and password.

However, their maybe a better way...

I take it that the system that's running the tests and doing a commit can commit as itself without a password (or use the `--password` parameter since it knows its own password).

You can have the system commit the changes as itself, then modify the name of the commit user by changing the `svn:author` revision property on a particular revision.

```
$ svn ps --revprop -r $revision svn:author $patch_submitter $repository_url
```

The only thing you need to do is to setup a pre-revprop-change hook in your repository. This is a safety issue since you don't want users to change revision properties willy-nilly. There are three main ones: `svn:log` which is the user's commit message, `svn:author`, and `svn:date` which is the commit date. Since there is no versioning of these properties, there's no way to catch if these got changed. Thus, the hook must be there to change revision properties.

However, setting up a hook isn't hard. Just check if the user wanting to make the change is the patch system.

Comment: Thanks David. yes, the system can commit itself without a password. Changing the svn:author seems to be a viable solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Commiting using ssh with keys doesn't prompt for a password. Also check the answer here: [SVN: How to commit without entering password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443773/svn-how-to-commit-without-entering-password)

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, only http/https mehod is allowed where i work.